# Update a reactive data in axios response callback inside setup option - Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am making a Axios call in the Setup method of my component. I want to then set a variable called books. In vue 2 I would make the call in a created hook and then use `this` to set the variable. In vue 3 there is no `this` available in the setup method so how do you access data outside the axios call? I want to get an array of books and then set it to the books variable. How would this be done and is there a better way to do this in Vue 3? My setup method looks like:

```
  setup() {
      let books = reactive<Array<Book>>([])
        HTTP.get('/books')
            .then(response => {
                //Normally here I would do this.books
                books = response.data
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
            return { books }
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [composition api docs](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#reactive) :

> **reactive**
> Takes an object and returns a reactive proxy of the original ...
> ...
> **ref**
> Takes an inner value and returns a reactive and mutable ref object. The ref object has a single property .value that points to the inner value ...

So the `reactive` function should have an inner property :

```
  setup() {
      let state = reactive<Array<Book>>({books:[]})
        HTTP.get('/books')
            .then(response => {
            
                state.books = response.data
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
            return { books:toRef(state,'books') }
  }
```

or use a `ref`

```
  setup() {
      let books = ref<Array<Book>>([])
        HTTP.get('/books')
            .then(response => {
              
                books.value = response.data
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
            return { books }
  }
```

Comment: Using reactive throw this error `Argument of type '{ books: undefined[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Book[]'.` maybe that's because it's expecting a single object? Using ref does work but from my understanding isn't ref to be used with primitive types? An Array is not so that's confusing.

Comment: This is a typing issue, could enrich the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-ts-y7bdv) in order to debug it

Comment: Yes ref are for primitive types, but it could takes object/array type

Comment: Hmm seems a little confusing that you can use both types. I apologize but I don't follow what you mean about enrich code? Should add my code to the sandbox?

Comment: I mean simulate this part of code in order to define the right type in reactive

Comment: I think its something with Vetur. Weirdly this works `const books = reactive({  }) as Array<Book>`. The code is slightly more verbose now then if I use refs due to the fact that I have to reference everything as `books.values` instead of just books. I wonder if there is a downside to using refs with none primitives?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224599/discussion-between-taylor-and-boussadjra-brahim).

Comment: it's `books.value` not `books.values`

Comment: Books.value does not work where as books.values does. Books.value throws `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Book[]'. Did you mean 'values'?`